# How to vectorize stop loss in backtest

Tags: programming, backtesting

I am building a custom vectorized backtester in python using pandas.
My problem is that the entry and exit signals are independent and can occur at the same time making it difficult to create a single position column
Using an event-based logic, I have solved the problem but then it is slow because of the for loop.
Here is a snapshot of the data for a long only case:
[image]

Ideally trade 1 should open in row 5 and close in row 6 and then open a trade in row 9 and close in row 11
So ignore entry signals in row 6 and exit signals in rows 4,5 and 8
Hope this makes sense

Comment: Could you give some code snippets of what you tried so far?

Comment: Since the interpretation of the two signals at time t depends on the state (long or flat) at time t-1, the decision making has to be sequential.  (However, that should still be relatively fast, using a single scan of all sorted rows).

Comment: @nbbo2 do you believe there is any way of vectorization of the logic you described?

Comment: @vonjd I only have the for loop.

Comment: R has an efficient implementation of something called „run length encoding“. Maybe there’s an equivalent in Python. Sorry for being vague here.

Comment: What does it mean that you have an open and an exit at the same time? No change? Can an open signal be given when you already have an open position?

Comment: Might be a stupid question but why do you use Python for this anyway? R is very well suited for this (as @Kermittfrog pointed out). You might want to have a look at my blog post here: https://blog.ephorie.de/backtest-trading-strategies-like-a-real-quant